# SQL query getting row with longest string

Tags: sql, postgresql

Given this query:

```
SELECT
    LENGTH(app) AS app_length, 
    ROW_NUMBER() 
OVER (
    PARTITION BY 
        vid, basevid
    ORDER BY 
        vid, basevid, LENGTH(app) 
    ) AS j,
    vid, basevid, app
FROM DATA4 WHERE hol = '40008'
```

That returns this data:

```
app_length,j,vid,basevid,app
2,1,6260,3174,"AT"
2,2,6260,3174,"AT"
9,3,6260,3174,"AT; TH125"
9,4,6260,3174,"AT; TH125"
18,5,6260,3174,"AT; TH125 gasoline"
18,6,6260,3174,"AT; TH125 gasoline"
2,1,6261,3175,"AT"
2,2,6261,3175,"AT"
9,3,6261,3175,"AT; TH125"
9,4,6261,3175,"AT; TH125"
18,5,6261,3175,"AT; TH125 gasoline"
18,6,6261,3175,"AT; TH125 gasoline"
2,1,6260,3174,"AT"
2,2,6260,3174,"AT"
9,3,6260,3174,"AT; TH125"
9,4,6260,3174,"AT; TH125"
18,5,6260,3174,"AT; TH125 gasoline"
18,6,6260,3174,"AT; TH125 gasoline"
2,1,6262,3176,"AT"
2,2,6262,3176,"AT"
9,3,6262,3176,"AT; TH125"
9,4,6262,3176,"AT; TH125"
18,5,6262,3176,"AT; TH125 gasoline"
18,6,6262,3176,"AT; TH125 gasoline"
2,1,6262,3176,"AT"
2,2,6262,3176,"AT"
9,3,6262,3176,"AT; TH125"
9,4,6262,3176,"AT; TH125"
18,5,6262,3176,"AT; TH125 gasoline"
18,6,6262,3176,"AT; TH125 gasoline"
2,1,6262,3176,"AT"
2,2,6262,3176,"AT"
9,3,6262,3176,"AT; TH125"
9,4,6262,3176,"AT; TH125"
18,5,6262,3176,"AT; TH125 gasoline"
18,6,6262,3176,"AT; TH125 gasoline"
2,1,10182,4599,"AT"
9,2,10182,4599,"AT; TH125"
18,3,10182,4599,"AT; TH125 gasoline"
2,1,10328,4651,"AT"
9,2,10328,4651,"AT; TH125"
18,3,10328,4651,"AT; TH125 gasoline"
2,1,9830,4453,"AT"
2,2,9830,4453,"AT"
9,3,9830,4453,"AT; TH125"
9,4,9830,4453,"AT; TH125"
18,5,9830,4453,"AT; TH125 gasoline"
18,6,9830,4453,"AT; TH125 gasoline"
2,1,9830,4453,"AT"
2,2,9830,4453,"AT"
9,3,9830,4453,"AT; TH125"
9,4,9830,4453,"AT; TH125"
18,5,9830,4453,"AT; TH125 gasoline"
18,6,9830,4453,"AT; TH125 gasoline"
2,1,4650,2560,"AT"
2,2,4650,2560,"AT"
9,3,4650,2560,"AT; TH125"
9,4,4650,2560,"AT; TH125"
18,5,4650,2560,"AT; TH125 gasoline"
18,6,4650,2560,"AT; TH125 gasoline"
```

How would I return the record with the longest app string or the longest app_length by vid and basevid?

The results I need is:

```
app_length,j,vid,basevid,app
18,6,6261,3175,"AT; TH125 gasoline"
18,6,6260,3174,"AT; TH125 gasoline"
18,6,6262,3176,"AT; TH125 gasoline"
18,3,10182,4599,"AT; TH125 gasoline"
18,3,10328,4651,"AT; TH125 gasoline"
18,6,9830,4453,"AT; TH125 gasoline"
18,6,4650,2560,"AT; TH125 gasoline"
```

The table has 40 million records so this has to be fast, too.

Comment: I am not sure why this question is getting downvotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `distinct on`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (hol, vid, base_vid) d.*
FROM DATA4 d
WHERE hol = '40008'
ORDER BY hol, vid, basevid, LENGTH(app) DESC;
```

This is probably the fastest method in Postgres.  It would be faster with an index on `(hol, vid, basevid, LENGTH(app) desc)`.

Comment: That pulls the shortest length app value.

Comment: `LENGTH(app) DESC` should pull the *longest*, not the *shortest*.